# Выравнивание div

Tags: html, css

Значит, есть у нас div style='width:1024px;'.
Необходимо в этот див запихнуть *произвольное* количество других div'ов так, что бы они растянулись по ширине на весь родительский div. И что бы у всех была одинаковая ширина.
**Без JS**.
Как это выглядит:
 1. У нас 2 дочерних элемента. Каждый по 512 в ширине.
 2. Добавляем третий элемент в исходный код. Обновляем страницу. Ширина каждого дочернего стала 1024/3.
 3. Добавляем четвертый. Ширина каждого стала 1024/4=256.
Дочерние элементы выводятся не стабильным количеством, а каждый раз разным.
Т.е. прописать каждому ширину - не вариант. Они сами должны "определить" себе ширину так, что бы в сумме ширина была 1024.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Появилась идея через table td td td сделать, но хотелось бы через css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что то типа:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #content {
                display: table;
                width: 1024px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
            #content div {
                display: table-cell;
                border: 1px solid #f00;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: благодарю. работает :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё так:

```
<div class="content">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<style>
  .content {display: block; width: 1024px; clear: both;}
  .content div {display: inline-block; width: calc(1024px / 3); float: left;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/56gpmymL/